# Calculate the curvilinear integral

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the curve integral. This should be the curve integral of I rank, which can be calculated with the formula :

$$\int_{C}f(x,y)ds=\int_{a}^{b}f(g(t),h(t)) \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+\frac{dy}{dt})^2} \, dt$$

But I am not sure what to do with the absolute value equation for $l$.

$$\int_{l:|x|+|y|=a}xyds$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The line $l$ is a square of vertices $A=(-a,0),B=(0,a),C=(a,0),D=(0,-a)$ that can be parametrized, separating the sides, as:
$$
AB \rightarrow (-1+t,t) \qquad t \in[0,1]
$$
$$
BC \rightarrow (t,1-t) \qquad t \in[0,1]
$$
$$
CD \rightarrow (1-t,-t) \qquad t \in[0,1]
$$
$$
DA \rightarrow (-t,-1+t) \qquad t \in[0,1]
$$